# ESP32DMASPI in ardunio uno as SPI master

Tags: arduino, esp32, spi

I am trying to configure **Arduino uno as SPI-master** and **ESP32 as SPI-slave** using hideakitai/ESP32DMASPI , when I am compiling the code for esp32 it is compiling successfully but when I select Arduino board it is showing an errors.

The error - fatal error: driver/spi_master.h: No such file or directory

I searched a lot about the issue & for **driver/spi_master.h** library, but not getting the proper help.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using, [hideakitai/ESP32DMASPI](https://github.com/hideakitai/ESP32DMASPI) is written for the ESP32, not the Arduino Uno.

The Arduino Uno is completely different processor from the ESP32 and uses a completely different implementation of the Arduino framework. The Uno's low level hardware (SPI, DMA, I2C, etc) is different from the ESP32's. The library you're using is not intended to work on the Arduino Uno and as you've seen it does not.

You need to find a library that does support the Uno or learn a whole lot about low level coding and rewrite the library you're trying to use to work with the Uno.

Comment: Thank's for the  reply, 

On the Arduino website it is mentioned that the library is compatible and can be used for other Arduino boards also.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/esp32dmaspi/

Comment: It clearly is not. The actual code is clear on that. The Arduino website is incorrect. The code's repository is not.

Comment: I tried to look for some other resources but most of them are from ESP32 to ESP32. Is there any other way to implement the same?

Comment: I answered this question in the answer, sorry. You either learn low level hardware coding for the target and write it our you find a library that supports the desired CPU.

Comment: Why do you think you need a special library for the Uno instead of just using its standard SPI support?

Comment: Ok i was not sure that the standard SPI library will work with ESP32.